# Unreal Engine 4 Error 2738

Tags: unreal-4

I am having trouble installing UE4 on my computer. I keep getting Error 2738 as I start the installation and can't find a fix. Even Microsoft Fix It 50842 won't work.

I've attempted to re-download installer, reboot, use a flash drive. Still the same error.

Anybody else been having this issue? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: You can try https://answers.unrealengine.com/
The community is pretty active, and Epic staff does go through bug/issue reports and helps solve them :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a third-party product.